# php open tag was automatically changed with <!--?php

Tags: php, apache

I don't know why. I'm using php7.0.1,apache2.4.18,mysql5.6.28. My php code is like

```
<?php
    echo "hello world";
 ?>
```

and I find it turns out to be this in the browser

```
<!--?php
echo "hello world";
?-->
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

**EDIT** 
I've uploaded the related files to https://github.com/franklee0817/publicFiles

Comment: I find that really hard to believe, I think you haven't showed us everything.

Comment: what do you want. Just tell me.

Comment: I was using Vagrant and VirtualBox. The box of CentOS 7.1 is from http://www.vagrantbox.es/ (on github is https://github.com/CommanderK5/packer-centos-template/releases/download/0.7.1/vagrant-centos-7.1.box)

Comment: Is this all of the code? And is the file named php, and not html?

Comment: The php7,mysql5.6 and apache2.4 is installed through oneinstack  https://github.com/lj2007331/oneinstack

Comment: Well `<p>I AM HTML</p>` in `PHP` would throw an error so I'd guess this isn't being run through `PHP`. https://eval.in/498082

Comment: The file named info.php and that is all it's code. It's a test file. There something wrong. So I write this simple file to test if php works and which version of php is runing on the apache.

Comment: please check php.ini file. look for some misconfiguration. please, look in the apache2 config files also, try to find any undesired module that is in the server's process chain

Comment: @RaffaelBecharaRameh What good should such a comment do? It basically says: something may be configured wrong on your system. I guess the OP assumes that much...

Comment: I'm not familiar the php.ini and httpd.conf file. So I just changed what I have to.  May I post this two file here?

Comment: If what you posted really is what you get in your browser, then please take a closer look. Your browser should offer some option to show the "source code" of that html page it received. Note: that is _not_ the php source code. Is there something more to be seen? I suspect your code (which is invalid php) throws an error and some error handler wants to show you the code leading to the error...

Comment: Yeah I know the developer tools. I change the info.php with <?php echo "hello world"; ?> and I get <!--?php echo "hello world"; ?--> <html><head></head><body></body></html> from the browser.

Comment: I put the settings here https://github.com/franklee0817/publicFiles

Comment: It looks like the web server doesn't pass the PHP source file to the PHP interpreter and sends it verbatim back to the browser. And you didn't get from the browser the exact response body received from the server but some HTML that was generated by the browser from the internal document structure it parsed from the HTML received from the server. As you already found out, the developer tools is the culprit. Find the "view source" command of your browser; that's the content received from the server. Or, even better, use `curl` or `wget` to do the request and see the response unaltered.

Comment: ➜  ~  curl http://dev.happylike.com/info.php                      ➜  
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>%                                                                                                  ➜  ~

Comment: @arkascha My comment is far valid! It opens the eyes of the readers that don't know such files exists and module chains exists! It tells the man to search for information about those concepts. Don't you see, man?!

Comment: @RaffaelBecharaRamehYou refer to a developer who does not know that there is such thing as a configuration? And you tell _me_ to open my eyes? LOL

Answer (score 1):

Your server is clearly not parsing PHP code so PHP tags reach the browser. If you see the actual source code (each browser has a different menu item but keyboard short-curt is often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) you'll see your raw PHP source code. However, if you use the DOM tree provided by your browser developer tools you'll the result of parsing and fixing the HTML tag soup. Applying workarounds to invalid tags is left to browser discretion; yours have decided to entirely omit `<?php ... >` and wrap it into a comment tag.

Comment: Configure Apache to parse PHP code? Sorry, I just answered your question of why PHP tags gets changed. PHP has [comprehensive documentation on how to install it](http://php.net/manual/en/install.php) and I don't have the faintest idea about your environment.

Answer (score -1):

I find out what's wrong with my server. The php code is not actually running with php. The apache give the php code straight to browser. everything works properly after I add the below line in httpd.conf.

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

The handler for php was missing. It should be as a default line in httpd.conf, I don't know why it was missing. But after this. Everything back on line. Thank you guys.